# Manage Multiple ViewControllers from a TableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm curious if anyone has ideas for managing multiple ViewControllers from a TableView.  I have a list of roughly seven items I am displaying in a TableView with a ViewController dedicated to each.  My first thought is to initialize an array with the various ViewControllers.

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:7];
[viewControllers addObject:[[ViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View1" bundle:nil]];
[viewControllers addObject:[[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View2" bundle:nil]];
...
```

Then reference that array to load the appropriate view on item selection.

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[viewControllers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] animated:YES];
}
```

I'm really not sure if this is an appropriate approach.  Any direction would be great.

**EDITED:**

Based on the feedback from Ryan and Joe I implemented an object to hold my table items. Abbreviating my problem also caused some confusion on implementation details.  Added the full solution to manage both view controllers and selecting tab bar items.

TableNavigationItem.h

```
#import 


@interface TableNavigationItem : NSObject {
    NSString *title;
    NSNumber *tabIndex;
    id viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *tabIndex;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id viewController;

@end
```

TableNavigationItem.m

```
#import "TableNavigationItem.h"


@implementation TableNavigationItem

@synthesize title;
@synthesize viewController;

- (id) init{

    if(self = [super init]){
        self.title = @"";
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    [title release];
    [tabIndex release];
    [viewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Then initialize per Joe's suggestion.

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:7];
TableNavigationItem *navItem;

// view 1
navItem = [[TableNavigationItem alloc] init];
navItem.title = @"View 1";
navItem.tabIndex = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
[mutableArray addObject:navItem];
[navItem release];

// view 2
navItem = [[TableNavigationItem alloc] init];
navItem.title = @"View 2";
navItem.viewController = [ViewController2 class]];
[mutableArray addObject:navItem];
[navItem release];

...

// store the navigation items
self.tableItems = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray];
[mutableArray release];
```

Then

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    TableNavigationItem *navItem = [tableItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if(navItem.viewController != nil){
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[[navItem.viewController alloc] init] autorelease] animated:YES];
    }
    else if(navItem.tabIndex != nil){
        [((MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).tabBarController setSelectedIndex:[navItem.tabIndex integerValue]];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point of TableNavigationItem here. Why not make `title` a method on `ViewController1` and `ViewController2`? Then your array could be: `viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[ViewController1 class], [ViewController2 class], nil]` and your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` could simply call `[self.navigationController pushViewController:[[[[viewControllers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] alloc] init] autorelease] animated:YES]`.

Comment: Also, if `tableItems` is a retained property, the `copy` call will cause a leak unless you autorelease that resultant array. But you can always just assign to the NSMutableArray (who will know the difference?), and let it be `[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:7]` or better yet `-[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:..., nil]`! It might also help you to read up on Cocoa's memory management and object lifecycles.

Comment: +1 As presented, TableNavigationItem is a bit redundant. I removed some of my use case to simplify the question (I have a few navigation items that navigate a tab bar controller).  Guess I should have presented the entire problem.

Comment: +1 And you're right.  I didn't realize copy was increasing the retain count (I rarely use it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the views those controllers manage are visible on the screen immediately, there is nothing wrong with that approach. Make sure you release the array of VC's in `-viewDidUnload`, and recreate it in `-viewDidLoad`, so the runtime can unload all those extra objects when the next view is pushed onscreen. And be aware, only the root view controller will receive view lifecycle events; The view controllers you create and manually add the owned views to the table will not get those methods called. You'll have to implement some plumbing to get those view lifecycle events into the 'subviews', through notification or delegation.

The best answer to your question is "Instrument it". Run the Allocations and VM instruments at a minimum, and check to see how much memory those view controllers are consuming. If you want to improve your skillz with Instruments, watch the Performance session from WWDC 2011, they did a great job teaching how to use it to find memory and performance issues.

Comment: Thanks Ryan.  Check for answering first.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds fine to me. The only concern I would have is whether your view controllers are RAM-heavy, in which case you may want to make a decision: is it better to preallocate everything (i.e. are you sure you can fit all of those controllers' state within available memory?) or is it better to take the latency hit to load the appropriate view controller as-needed?

It looks like your ViewControllers are of different classes. If that's the case (and if each one always uses the same respective nib), I would consider implementing a custom `-init` method on each and making your array of choices one of `Class` objects. That's just a matter of personal preference, though.

One more thing: You will want to autorelease those view controllers or you'll leak memory no matter what.

Comment: Why would you autorelease the view controllers - as soon as the array is released, any controller not part of the view hierarchy is going to be released. If you autorelease them instead, all the controllers will remain in memory even after the array is released, until the device experiences memory pressure or the pool is drained.

Comment: The code above used `[viewControllers addObject:[[ViewController1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View1" bundle:nil]];` with an array. That gives the controller a retainCount of 2 already, and 3 when it gets pushed (right?). When the VC gets popped, that's -1, when the array gets deallocated, that's another -1, and then we still have 1 floating around. At least on the desktop, autoreleasing pools drain pretty frequently afaik.

Comment: To clarify, I'm saying those initialization lines should read: `[viewControllers addObject:[[[VCClass alloc] initWithNibName...] autorelease]]`.

Comment: Thanks Joe.  +1 all around for the autorelease tips.

Comment: @joe is right, I misread the code. Since you're init'ing the controller directly in the `addObject:` method, you'll have to autorelease them. If you want to follow slightly stricter memory management rules, which may or may not have an impact on memory usage, you could create the controllers first (in local variables), add those to the array, then release the controllers. At that point, the array would own the controllers and release them when appropriate, instead of depending on autorelease pools to drain.

Comment: @RyanR Not to belabor this point, but I want to clear up any confusion about `autorelease`. As soon as that array `dealloc`s, its contained objects will be sent a `-release` message--no problem there. If you sent `autorelease` to the objects when you inserted them, they would receive `-release` when the runloop's pool is deallocated, which is at the end of the run loop as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766839/end-of-run-loop-autorelease-pool-recovery/5767235#5767235). Unless you're doing many allocations in a tight loop, you shouldn't worry about when the pool drains.

Comment: So, in summary, it's fine to "depend[] on autorelease pools to drain" because that happens very frequently. For seven `alloc`s it won't make a substantial difference, it's not at all an unpredictable behavior, and it will make the code read more cleanly IMO. Note that in this specific case, Jason only needs to do a single allocation (the array) until a view controller is actually needed, at which time it's one more. See my comment on the original question.